# Is it possible to recover a Diskcryptor volume password?

Tags: encryption, passwords, disk-encryption, password-cracking, data-recovery

Must admit to being dumb: I have encrypted one partition from my external hard drive with the AES-Twofish-Serpent algorithm and used a key file with a password.

My PC ran into a problem and now the file is empty. This was a year ago, and now I need that info. I checked and I wasn't able to recover the information in the file.

I know how long the string is, somewhere between 22-28 characters and I know all letters, symbols, and numbers that can be in there.

Is it somehow possible to recover the data or to make a script to bruteforce using my information with words, numbers, and symbols I know are included?

Comment: If it was possible, encrypting your disk would be pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, no.

The whole point of the system's security is that there is no way to retrieve it other than brute forcing, and at that password length the entire key space will take a considerable amount longer than your life to brute force!

Unless you wrote it down or stored it elsewhere, you'll need to assume whatever was in that encrypted space is gone.